# How to stop Office Outlook 2010 from butchering links in the emails that I send out?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

At work we use Outlook 2010 for our emails:

[image]

Recently I faced an issue when I was trying to email a link to our partner that was chopped into pieces by Outlook's need to break text into paragraphs. Here's what the person got on their end:

[image]

See `dl=0` part is on several lines. This obviously made the link in the email unusable.

It's kinda obvious, but is there a way to prevent Microsoft from butchering my links?

Comment: Try wrapping the url in double quotes. ie: `"https://dropbox.com/s/a1blah/blah.zip/dl=0"`.  Also consider that it may be the recipient's mail program that not handing the link properly, and if so it's their fault, not yours. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the encoding to UTF-8 should solve the issue.

> [How to prevent Outlook 2010 and 2013 from adding line breaks to sent plain text messages](http://blog.techhit.com/551102-how-to-prevent-outlook-2010-and-2013-from-adding-line-breaks-to-sent-plain-text-messages)
>
> When you send a plain text message, by default, Outlook will wrap text
>   and insert line breaks at 76 characters. This might break your
>   formatted paragraphs and URL links.
>
> There is a solution which requires registry changes, however there
>   also an option that fixes it without touching the registry. Here are
>   the steps:
>
> 1. Click on the File tab and select Options.
> 2. Click on “Advanced” in the left column of the Options window.
> 3. Scroll down to the “International Options” section.
> 4. Change “Preferred encoding for outgoing messages” to “Unicode (UTF-8)”.
> 5. Click “OK” at the bottom of the Options window.
> 6. Restart Outlook
>
> That should do it.
>
> Note: This only works for Outlook 2013 and 2010.

Comment: Thank you. One would think Microsoft would be "smart enough" to do this by default... as even my old Outlook Express in Windows XP can parse text and not break for paragraphs on URLs. But oh well...